# Input in Char Array without Duplicates Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, duplicates

Imagine I have this:

```
String input = "AB   BC";   //  ( Just an Example)
```

I want to put this String into an char array, but i want to have no duplicates
and blank symbols in my char Array. My solution so far:

```
String input = "AB  BC"

char array[]=input.toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Data at ["+i+"]="+array[i]);
}
```

The Output is :

```
This is my input String AB  BC 
This is the content of my Char Array
Data at [0]=A
Data at [1]=B
Data at [2]= 
Data at [3]= 
Data at [4]=B
Data at [5]=C
Data at [6]=
```

So now I don't know how I can erase the duplicates and the blank symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will add only the chars without any blanks to the hashset

```
char array[]=input.toCharArray();
Set<Character> m=new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(array[i]!=' ')
      m.add(array[i])
}
Character[] text = m.toArray(new Character[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`LinkedHashSet<Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (to maintain insertion order).

1. Use the [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method on your String object to replace whitespaces
2. Transform your String in a char array
3. For each char add it to the `Set` (a Set doesn't allow duplicates)
4. Use [`toArray(T[] object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method to get back a `Character` array.

So it would be something like this :

```
        String input = "AB  BC";
        input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        Set<Character> s = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        for(char c : input.toCharArray())
            s.add(c);

        Character [] array = s.toArray(new Character[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output :

```
[A, B, C]
```

If you want to have back an array of primitive you can use (note that you have to use the apache commons library) [`char[] arr = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(array);`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Character%5B%5D%29)

Here's the source code :

```
2647      public static char[] toPrimitive(Character[] array) {
2646            if (array == null) {
2647                return null;
2648            } else if (array.length == 0) {
2649                return EMPTY_CHAR_ARRAY;
2650            }
2651            final char[] result = new char[array.length];
2652            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
2653                result[i] = array[i].charValue();
2654            }
2655            return result;
2656        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Transfer content to `LinkedHashSet` . It will remove the duplicates for you !
Here's an [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedhashset_class.htm) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

use `Hashset` of generic type `character`

```
 HashSet<Character> m=new HashSet<Character>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LinkedHashSet but I assume you want an array at the end.  You can do this.

```
String input = ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BitSet seen = new BitSet(); // more compact than a HashSet<Character>
seen.set(' ');              // pretend we have seen space already
for(char ch: input.toCharArray()) {
    if(!seen.get(ch)) {
        sb.append(ch);
        seen.set(ch);
    }
}
char[] unique = sb.toString().toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this:

```
String input = "AB  BC";
char array[]=input.toCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if(!input.substring(0,i).contains(array[i]+"") && array[i]!=' ')
      System.out.println("Data at ["+i+"]="+array[i]);
}
```

*Output:*

```
Data at [0]=A
Data at [1]=B
Data at [5]=C
```